# Hypergeometric and Poisson distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the Poldavian State Lottery, five balls are drawn (without replacement) from a drum filled with balls numbered from $1$ to $45$. When buying a ticket an entrant chooses five numbers between 1 and 45 inclusive. To win a prize in a lottery, at least three of the balls drawn must match numbers on one’s ticket. To win the jackpot, all five balls drawn must match the numbers on one’s ticket.
(a) What is the probability that a given ticket wins a prize?
(b) The population of Poldavia is two million, and on one particular draw each resident buys one ticket, choosing their numbers at random, with each ticket being equiprobable, and all residents choose their tickets independently. What is the probability that there are (i) no jackpot winners? (ii) exactly one jackpot winner? (iii) an even number of jackpot winners? (NB zero is an even number).

For (a) I got $\sum_{k=3}^{5} \frac{\dbinom{5}{k}\dbinom{40}{5-k}}{\dbinom{45}{5}}$

For (b): $N=\dbinom{45}{5}=1221759$
$ M=2000000$ 
and using hypergeometric distribution
$P(X=k)=\dbinom{M}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{N^k}(1-\frac{1}{N})^{M-k}$, aproximated in the following way: $P(X=k)\simeq\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{M}{N})^ke^{-\frac{M}{N}}$ (Poisson distribution). So it becomes easy to compute $P(X=0)$ and $P(X=1)$. But when I try $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X=2k)$ I notice the result it gets very close to $\frac{1}{2}$ so I suppose there should be a way to get the exact result as $\frac{1}{2}$.  Please let me know if it is and you know it.